# Trouble intersecting a polyline and contours (Hack index / stream length gradient index)

Tags: intersection, contour, line, spatial-join

Working on creating polylines for measurement using SL index (hack index). So far I have the main trunk of a stream, and contours at 10m. What I am trying to do is

a) get the elevation at each intersection of the stream (polyline) and a contour for the full length of the stream

b)get the distance along the stream between each contour intersection

So far I've been able use spatial join to get the contact between the stream and the contour but the distance is off (checked by using measure tool on the polyline of the full stream and summing them in the attribute table)

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: arcgis 10.1 or global mapper 15

Comment: Hi, you have an image of the problem?

Comment: No picture of the problem, just can't figure out a workflow to get all of the data that I need.